# Stream Socket Access denied Windows Phone 8.1 Bluetooth

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

I try to connect a Bluetooth device with my Windows Phone (8.1) with the StreamSocket-Class.

Now every time I call socket.CallAsync(HostName, RemoteServiceName) I get an AccessDenied Error. I activated the Proximity sensor in the AppManifest.

Here is the code:

```
private async void ConnectToDevice()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            // Disposing the socket with close it and release all resources associated with the socket
            _socket.Dispose();
        }

        try
        {
            _socket = new StreamSocket();

            // Note: If either parameter is null or empty, the call will throw an exception
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(_currentPeer.HostName, "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}");

            // If the connection was successful, the RemoteAddress field will be populated
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(_socket.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName);
            await md.ShowAsync();

            Start.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Connection failed");
            await md.ShowAsync();

            _socket.Dispose();
            _socket = null;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you add a declaration for your device in the DeviceCapabilities section in the appxmanifest?

Comment: Yes, I activated Proximity for Bluetooth and Internet (Client & Server) for the Socket connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. But finally I've found a solution at http://www.codefest.at/post/2014/02/03/Bluetooth-in-Windows-81-Apps-nutzen.aspx

The Internet (Client & Server) capability doesn't do the trick. It's a riddle to me why MS doesn't provide the bluetooth capability in the GUI of Visual Studio.

Just add the following xml into your appxmanifest:

```xml
<Capabilities>
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

Regards