# Windows Phone 8.1 ID_CAP_NETWORKING

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows phone 8.1 app development and I am trying develop application for Windows Phone 8.1, wich will be using bluetooth. My problem is that everywhere, where I looked is that i have to add capability ID_CAP_NETWORKING to my WMAppManifest.xaml, but in my project I have only Package.appmanifest.xaml where isn't any ID_CAP_NETWORKING.
[It is all capabilities, wich i can add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb0Lu.png)

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: which IDE are you using? in VS2015, you should be able to set it in Project > Store > Edit App Manifest > Capabilities.

Comment: I am using VS2015 Comunity

Comment: you are right, in 8.1 solutions there might be no WMAppManifest.xaml at all. They have quite a bit of a "version nightmare" going on here... Could you have a look here, this may be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29539276/1132334